# how to extract data from emotive sdk in python?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a project where we(team of 3) are planning to make a software based on the emotive device (http://emotiv.com/), which has to save brain patterns corresponding to different objects and compares it with the same when the new patterns come. For example, a pattern of "Apple"(object) is saved previously. When a fresh user puts on the head set and thinks of apple, the match should occur and the apple must be recognized. What we are not getting is the part where we get raw data from the SDK software provided. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: do you have the full developers license or just the standard license?  If it is the latter, you cant get the raw data

Comment: We have Emotiv Research Edition SDK v2.0.0.20. Is there any way to know if it is full developers license? If it is a full developers license please tell us the method to extract data. Thank you vey much :)

Comment: Yes you are able to get the data.  Look in the c++ examples folder for using the SDK, it has an example.  Otherwise you can try open vibe or one of these methods https://code.google.com/p/adastra/wiki/EmotivEPOCH

Comment: also can try: http://daeken.com/emokit-hacking-the-emotiv-epoc-brain-computer-0

https://github.com/qdot/emokit